# Can't send mails from aplication on nodejs at an amazon ec2 server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, nodemailer

So, I have this application in nodejs that is hosted at an Amazon EC2 server. Among other stuff, this application has the function of sending emails, and it used to work normally. But, out of nowhere, the mails simply aren't getting sent anymore.
I use the exactly same configurations and general aplication structure locally, and it works normally. I also used the same exact configs and structure at the server until 2 weeks ago. I have no idea what could be causing the error.
Here's some code:

```
//mailConfig
module.exports = {
    host: hostname, 
    port: 465,
    user: user@name,
    pass: password   
}

//mailSender

const mailConfig = require("../config/mailConfig");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

 emailSend(req, res) {
        try {
            let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: mailConfig.host,
                port: mailConfig.port,
                secure: "SSL/TLS",
                auth: {
                    user: mailConfig.user,
                    pass: mailConfig.pass
                },
                tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
            });
            return transporter.sendMail({
                from: sender@address, // sender address
                to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
                subject: "Mail Subject", // Subject line
                html: "Mail Body" 
            }).then(info => {
                console.log("Message sent: %s", info.response);
                res.status(200).send();
            }).catch(error => res.status(400).send());
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

//Error after trying to send an email
Error: Connection timeout
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/mailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._onError (/mailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:760:20)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/mailer/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:555:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:498:7) {
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

I've already search the internet for any solution, but everything that I could find pointed out to the configs or structure - that is working normally locally.
If someone could at least point me towards an possible solution, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Adison Candido, this may be due to AWS restricting SMTP traffic, you need to open a ticket with AWS to have them remove SMTP restriction before sending email will work. They do this to prevent people from creating adhok spam clients.

Comment: @proxim0 I'll check that out and see if it solves. Thanks for bringing up the possibility!

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate app password from you email you want to use for sending the mail.

The steps are as follows:

- login to you Gmail account
- locate security tab
- navigate to signing in to Google
- enable 2 step authentication
- enter the code sent to your phone number
- return to signing in to Google
- Your will see App password
- click on it and generate a new app password.
- use it in your node.js application as password for Gmail.